# replace header "from" based on information stored in database for each email

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to simply change header from "user@domain"  into "full user name < user@domain >" for the outgoing emails taking the full user name from mysql database ?

the postfix documentation does not clarify how to have at the same time regex and mysql lookup table for header_checks and this is what I think I need.

Does anyone how now to solve the problem with different codepage ?   In my case users can use utf8 or windows1250 codepage to encode the headers.

Answer (score 2):

The `From:` header should really be set by the MUA (Mail User Agent, the software generating the message and handing it to postfix).

Relying on the MTA (Mail Transport Agent, postfix (or sendmail,qmail,exchange,...) to do this doesn't make sense - Presumably it's something you want to do to make the message more friendly for your users, but the MTA doesn't care about that: It just wants to pass the message along to the next server in line.

Comment: And header_checks are for incoming (SMTP) mails. Which underlines to do it on the MUA side.

Comment: making it by MUA means that I would have to educate all users what to put in the from: header to have unified version in the whole company or I would have to use another software to enforce such preferences in the mail clients